# PHP - concatenate ' checked' to each string value in multidimensional array using recursion

Tags: php, string, recursion, foreach, concatenation

I have a multidimensional array in PHP, and want to concatenate a string onto each string element using recursion. The array is as follows:

```
$array = Array
(
    [p] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Porsche 993 Carrera Cabriolet represents a great opportunity to acquire an open-top variant of one of the most coveted 911 models.
            [1] => First registered on 5 August 1994, M912 SGY displays 10,630 miles on the odometer with a clock change at 66,244 miles in 2014.
            [2] => The car’s Aventura Green metallic paintwork is reported to be in good condition, presenting well for its age and mileage.
            [3] => The Marble Grey leather interior is believed to be entirely original.
            [4] => Serviced by Porsche specialist Portiacraft in July 2020 at 76,598 miles, this consisted of an annual oil and filter service.
            [5] => The last MOT was undertaken on 6 July 2020 at 76,598 miles.
            [6] => It is supplied with a Porsche Club Great Britain folder with records of main dealer and specialist service history.
            [7] => This Porsche 911 Carrera Cabriolet presents in highly original and well-maintained condition.
            [8] => Summary of maintenance history:
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [strong] => The description of this auction lot is, to the best of the seller's knowledge, accurate and not misleading.
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [strong] =>  All UK-registered cars and motorbikes on Collecting Cars are run through an online HPI check. This vehicle shows no insurance database markers for damage or theft, and has no finance owing.
                )

        )

    [ul] => Array
        (
            [li] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 04/11/1996 – 16,120 miles
                    [1] => 18/11/1998 – 25,086 miles
                    [2] => 09/09/1999 – 28,769 miles
                    [3] => 21/02/2000 – 31,469 miles
                    [4] => 22/06/2001 – 36,055 miles
                    [5] => 29/10/2002 – 40,781 miles
                    [6] => 02/03/2005 – 46,238 miles
                    [7] => 24/03/2006 – 49,459 miles
                    [8] => 03/07/2007 – 53,051 miles
                    [9] => 17/12/2008 – 56,582 miles
                    [10] => 20/05/2010 – 57,385 miles
                    [11] => 08/06/2011 – 61,653 miles
                    [12] => 15/05/2012 – 64,425 miles
                    [13] => 17/04/2013 – 66,026 miles
                    [14] => 07/06/2014 – 66,244 miles
                    [15] => 14/09/2015 – 68,411 miles
                    [16] => 27/02/2018 – 74,856 miles
                    [17] => 06/08/2019 – ~76,400 miles
                    [18] => 06/07/2020 – 76,598 miles
                )

        )

)
```

Ideally, the result should look like this:

```
$array = Array
(
    [p] => Array
        (
            [0] => This Porsche 993 Carrera Cabriolet represents a great opportunity to acquire an open-top variant of one of the most coveted 911 models. checked
            [1] => First registered on 5 August 1994, M912 SGY displays 10,630 miles on the odometer with a clock change at 66,244 miles in 2014. checked
            [2] => The car’s Aventura Green metallic paintwork is reported to be in good condition, presenting well for its age and mileage. checked
            [3] => The Marble Grey leather interior is believed to be entirely original. checked
            [4] => Serviced by Porsche specialist Portiacraft in July 2020 at 76,598 miles, this consisted of an annual oil and filter service. checked
            [5] => The last MOT was undertaken on 6 July 2020 at 76,598 miles. checked
            [6] => It is supplied with a Porsche Club Great Britain folder with records of main dealer and specialist service history. checked
            [7] => This Porsche 911 Carrera Cabriolet presents in highly original and well-maintained condition. checked
            [8] => Summary of maintenance history: checked
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [strong] => The description of this auction lot is, to the best of the seller's knowledge, accurate and not misleading. checked
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [strong] =>  All UK-registered cars and motorbikes on Collecting Cars are run through an online HPI check. This vehicle shows no insurance database markers for damage or theft, and has no finance owing. checked
                )

        )

    [ul] => Array
        (
            [li] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 04/11/1996 – 16,120 miles checked
                    [1] => 18/11/1998 – 25,086 miles checked
                    [2] => 09/09/1999 – 28,769 miles checked
                    [3] => 21/02/2000 – 31,469 miles checked
                    [4] => 22/06/2001 – 36,055 miles checked
                    [5] => 29/10/2002 – 40,781 miles checked
                    [6] => 02/03/2005 – 46,238 miles checked
                    [7] => 24/03/2006 – 49,459 miles checked
                    [8] => 03/07/2007 – 53,051 miles checked
                    [9] => 17/12/2008 – 56,582 miles checked
                    [10] => 20/05/2010 – 57,385 miles checked
                    [11] => 08/06/2011 – 61,653 miles checked
                    [12] => 15/05/2012 – 64,425 miles checked
                    [13] => 17/04/2013 – 66,026 miles checked
                    [14] => 07/06/2014 – 66,244 miles checked
                    [15] => 14/09/2015 – 68,411 miles checked
                    [16] => 27/02/2018 – 74,856 miles checked
                    [17] => 06/08/2019 – ~76,400 miles checked
                    [18] => 06/07/2020 – 76,598 miles checked
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried the following:

```
$addedChecked = $this->addCheckedRecursive($array);

private function addCheckedRecursive($array)
    {
        if(!is_array($array)) {
            return $array . ' checked';
        }

        foreach($array as $v) {
            $this->addCheckedRecursive($v);
        }
    }
```

and also

```
$addedChecked = array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) {
            $value .= ' checked';
        });
```

The latter simply returned true.

For info, every element of each array will always be a string, and I would also like to preserve the current array structure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: would you mind posting what the result should look like, cause I didnt quite understand what is it that you want

Comment: 1) Undefined variable `$array` in `addCheckedRecursive` function - the parameter name is `$addedChecked`. 2) You're returning the value if it's a string but never using it (you never assign it anywhere). You might consider passing the original array by reference and directly modifying it (or pass a copy if you want to keep the original available).

Comment: @Tch Sure, I have edited my answer to show what I want to achieve

Comment: What else have you tried? This looks like a perfect exercise to learn some TDD

Comment: Also, what do want to achieve? The input and output array look pretty identical to me - so what's the difference?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to perform a translation operation on each string, but for the sake of simplicity I thought I'd just ask for each string to have ' checked' concatenated onto it

Comment: @Nico Haase all text elements have the word 'checked' at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an in-built function that you can use to achieve what you want.
If you use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php#refsect1-function.array-walk-recursive-description) as follows:

```
// Say you have your array $xmlArray
array_walk_recursive($xmlArray, function (&$value) {
    $value .= ' checked';
});

// Since $xmlArray is now modified (in place)
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xmlArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

In case you would not want $xmlArray to be changed as a side effect, could assign a value copy of the array to a new variable.

```
$addedChecked = $xmlArray;
array_walk_recursive($addedChecked, function (&$value) {
    $value .= ' checked';
});

// Since $addedChecked is now modified (in place)
echo '<pre>';
print_r($addedChecked);
echo '</pre>';
```

The function takes in the array by reference and will thus modify the array directly as a side effect of the function. This is one important thing to note, it does not return an array, but only whether the function was successfully executed on the array you gave it.

This will loop over each key => value pair and do so recursively if the value is of type array. You can simply concatenate to the value (where we pass value by reference) to update it with checked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this only returned 'true', I'm having a look into why

Comment: @HarrisE you only need to pass your array into the function, not assign the result of array_walk_recursive. It will change the array in place as it is passed by reference.

Comment: So I can't assign the resulting array to a variable? My code looks like this:  $addedChecked = array_walk_recursive($xmlArray, function (&$value) {
            $value .= ' checked';
        }); but the debugger says $addedChecked = true;

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($xmlArray, function (&$value) { $value .= ' checked'; });` Will modify `$xmlArray` which will then have checked concatenated to each value. @HarrisE

Comment: The boolean return value is only to indicate whether the function did successfully work or not. (see the docs in case)

Comment: Also if you do not walk `$xmlArray` to be changed you can always make a value copy by assigning `$myModifiedArray = $xmlArray` and passing `$myModifiedArray` to `array_walk_recursive`.

Comment: The top comment in the docs says: 
Since this is only mentioned in the footnote of the output of one of the examples, I feel it should be spelled out:

* THIS FUNCTION ONLY VISITS LEAF NODES *

That is to say that if you have a tree of arrays with subarrays of subarrays, only the plain values at the leaves of the tree will be visited by the callback function.  The callback function isn't ever called for a nodes in the tree that subnodes (i.e., a subarray).  This has the effect as to make this function unusable for most practical situations.

Comment: @HarrisE yes, and what are the leaf nodes in your case? The string values that you want checked to be concatednated to.

Comment: and sorry it's still not clear to me how I can make use of the updated array if it can't be assigned to anything

Comment: @HarrisE I added additional examples

Comment: Success! I understand it now and it's working. Thanks so much for your patience and talking me through how it works

Comment: @HarrisE no problem, sometimes concrete examples can clear up a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$addedChecked = $this->addCheckedRecursive($array);

private function addCheckedRecursive($array)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return $array . ' checked';
    }
    else
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            $array[$i] = $this->addCheckedRecursive($array[$i]);
        }
    
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask what $v is referring to?

Comment: Sorry, a little mistake I made converting your code into my answer. I corrected it now to use $array[$i] instead as $v does not exist anymore.

Comment: No problem, I have tried this method, but am getting the following error: Undefined offset: 0. It is referring to this line: $array[$i] = $this->addCheckedRecursive($array[$i]);

Comment: See my fixed amswer. The reason you're getting the error is because accidentally the string elements in the array also get processed as being an array in the second part of the code. A string does not have an index 0, hence the error. I put the array processing code in an else block to prevent this.

Comment: Sadly I'm still getting the same error. I thought a quick fix might be to add 
if(isset($array[$i])) {
  $array[$i] = $this->addCheckedRecursive($array[$i]);
} 

into the for loop, but this has just returned the original array

Comment: I did a little additional fix to my answer. I renamed the input parameter of addCheckedRecursive to $array. Did you have the parameter name correctly in your actual code?

Comment: I did, I passed in the original $array into addCheckedRecursive($array), it was a mistake on my part saying that I was passing in $addedChecked

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you have in your code function addCheckedRecursive($array) and then within the addCheckedRecursive function you also use $array? 

As a side note, I do think that using the build in functions array_walk_recursive and/or array_replace_recursive (which I did not know they existed) may be a better fit as they seem to provide a way shorter syntax.

Comment: It's working now, see the answer I've marked as correct. Thanks very much for your answer though

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try `array_walk_recursive` or `array_replace_recursive` ?

the docs can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)